# "React.createContext is not a function" - but I am not using it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am getting "React.createContext is not a function" error while running a react-native application. I searched for 'createContent' in the code, it doesn't exist.

Any idea what may be the reason for the error.

It is an iOS build of an app that is already running on android.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "newapp",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest --verbose --coverage",
    "test:update": "jest --verbose --coverage --updateSnapshot",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "coverage": "jest --verbose --coverage && xdg-open ./coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
    "lint": "npx eslint --fix ./src/*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "0.1.17",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "buffer": "5.1.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "graphql": "0.13.2",
    "graphql-tag": "2.10.0",
    "jasmine-react-helpers": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-apollo": "2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-elements": "0.19.0",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-link-preview": "^1.3.5",
    "react-native-login": "^0.0.1-alpha.2",
    "react-native-login-keycloak": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.2.6",
    "react-native-push-notification": "https://github.com/Dhanraj-bidchat/react-native-push-notification.git",
    "react-native-sleek-loading-indicator": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "6.2.2",
    "react-native-swipe-cards": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.6",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "5.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "victory-native": "0.17.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-only-warn": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "jest-resolve": "^23.0.0",
    "jest-serializer-enzyme": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.0.26",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest-setup.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native-safe-area-view|react-navigation|react-native-htmlview|react-native-fabric|react-native-login|react-native-elements|react-native-vector-icons|react-native-spinkit|victory-pie|victory-chart|victory-core|react-native-svg|react-native|redux-persist|victory-native|react-native-swipe-cards|react-native-swiper)/)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your package `react` and `react-dom` are not having the same version which is why you get the error. `react-dom@16.4.0` will want to have access to `React.createContext` but react@16.2.0 won't have it.

In order make it work run the following command:

```
yarn upgrade react@16.4.0
```

Or if you are using NPM:

```
npm install react@16.4.0
```

Comment: I tried the above fix on my react native 0.53 which had react 16.2 with the same error and I just got another error about `styled-components.native.cjs.js'`

Comment: I am having the same version of react and react-dom does not solve the problem and the issue **TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function** still persists.

Answer (score 32):

If this is happening using react 18 or Next JS 13. You are probably trying to use a client component functionalities in a server component. By default all components are treated as server components unless you explicitly specify.

To solve this and add the `"use client"` directive at the top of the file (before any imports). Here is more details on  [When to use Server vs. Client Components?](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#when-to-use-server-vs-client-components)

Comment: Any hint on how to debug? This can be very tricky to find out which component do not have "use client" in a 3rd party library

Comment: If you are on React 18 , You can tell which file is causing the issue from the console errors. Check and see if you are passing any client  directive like event listeners or react hooks.

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading React to React to 16.4.1

Comment: Upgrade can be painful. I will wait for other replies. Thank you!

Comment: Did you want to put a comment and posted it as an answer?

Comment: No. I remember having this issue. Upgrading to 16.4.1 solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using **npm** I solved it by upgrading to 16.4.1:

```
npm i react@16.4.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `@emotion/react` resulted in a similar error `TypeError: React.createContext is not a function`. The error disappeared after I removed `@emotion/react` and downgraded `@emotion/styled` from 11 to 10.

Comment: Can you please share a package.json to achieve the same. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see version 10 at @emotion/styled package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/react

Comment: Sorry, just saw these comments. I don't have the package.json anymore. My solution only applies when you get this issue if you add `@emotion/react` to your package.json.

Answer (score 2):

run

```
npm install react@latest
```

and

```
npm install react-dom@latest
```

fixed my error with this update.

Answer (score 0):

If `npm i react@latest react-dom@latest` doesn't work try doing `npm update` , it will update all packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing createContext

```js
import React, { createContext } from "react";
```