# React Native - TypeError: n.createContext is not a function. (In 'n.createContext(o.default)', 'n.createContext' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement React Native into an existing Android application. I follow the steps in the official documentation and I have ended with the following error when I compile the app (Although I receive an error the build is successful).

---

**On my phone:**

[image: The error]

---

**In Android Studio emulator:**

[image]

**Has someone faced the same issue?**

**Is the [official React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) wrong?**

Comment: An answer on the question if someone had the same experience won't help you, but you want to get a problem solved, don't you? Provide the compile-error and if possible some more relevant code. You can find some hints how to write good questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @David The first screenshot is actually the compile error. I can't provide any more details on this issue because these are only errors I've got.

Comment: [CreateContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) looks like a function on application level, so it's perhaps related to the viewport or some basic app. But I'm neither working with Android, not Java or or reactjs. So good luck that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the React context API yourself, this is likely to be related to a mismatch between your React version and the version of some other dependency like react-dom

Please check in your package.json if react-dom and react versions match.
You can upgrade the react version to solve the problem
`yarn upgrade react react-dom`

Also see these similar questions:

["React.createContext is not a function" - but I am not using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302725/react-createcontext-is-not-a-function-but-i-am-not-using-it)

[_react.default.createContext is not a function when using react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521723/react-default-createcontext-is-not-a-function-when-using-react-redux)

Comment: There is no react-dom in my package.json file.